# wso2esb & WMQ 7.5

Tags: ibm-mq, wso2-esb

I've a problem: I need to send messages (only send) to IBM MQ 7.5. In my case I have a lot of dynamic queues on several managers, so it isn't possible to send messages via jndi (like described in wso2 doc).
IBM MQ has a jms extension where I can send messages directly to queue manager and queue by specifying in q name (for example "queue://QM1/qName1"). But to do this I need to specify Connection Factory like these

```
<bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        <property name="port" value="${mq.port}"/>
        <property name="transportType" value="${mq.transportType}"/>
        <property name="hostName" value="#{props['host']}"/>
        <property name="queueManager" value="#{props['mq.manager']}"/>
        <property name="channel" value="#{props['mq.chanel']}"/>
    </bean>
```

But I doesn't find how I can specify factory in wso2esb. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question here is "If you are using dynamic queues, how do you know the name of the queue that you want to send to?"

The obvious answer to that question is "It's in the Reply-To fields."

Assuming that the message just received is in `rqstMsg` and that you want to send `replyMsg`, it might look something like this:

```
MessageProducer replyProducer = session.createProducer((Queue rqstMsg.getJMSReplyTo());
// create replyMsge here
replyProducer.send(replyMsg);
```

You specified "only send" so there's a possibility you are not replying to request messages. (Although if that is the case, how you are determining the dynamic queue names outside the context of a request message is an interesting question.)  If in fact you do not have a message with ReplyTo fields set, you can just specify the fully-qualified name of the destination:

```
MQQueue destQ = new MQQueue(rQMName, rName);
Destination dest = (Destination) destQ;
```

You would set the remote QMgr name in rQMName and the remote queue name in rName, then use the destination as normal.

Comment: I cannot do this way, because in wso2esb I can define sender for IBM MQ like these <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</parameter>. and for your code i need another connect factory

Comment: It's Java. You can instantiate any object from scratch and use the constructors and setter methods to populate it correctly.  The administered objects are a convenience but not at all required. Look for the nojndi samples and read [*IBM WebSphere Developer Technical Journal: Running a standalone Java application on WebSphere MQ V6.0*](http://ibm.co/c6jlIW) which also has sample code.